# How to show image in drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway to show image in the drop down menu in Php ?
I tried to embedding my code wit this tutorial code: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

```
<?php if ($data->URL->Visible) { // URL ?>
        <td<?php echo $data->URL->CellAttributes() ?>>
<div<?php echo $data->URL->ViewAttributes() ?>><?php echo $data->URL->ListViewValue() ?></div>
        <?php
        //echo '<pre>';var_dump($data->URL);echo '</pre>';
echo "<select name='webmenu' id='webmenu' ><option value='".$data->URL->EditValue."'>".$data->URL->EditValue."</option>";
echo  "<option value='1' data-image='img/tim.png'>True</option>";
echo  "<option value='0' data-image='img/do.png'>False</option>";
echo "</select>";
?>
</span></td>
<?php } ?>
```

But it really turn my page into a mess, coz I don't really have 'body' tag in my php page, and the header I import from my header file. So I think I can't put that code inside mine properly, and it may not work for php page also...
And I think there should be more straightforward method that people already use with php page for displaying image in drop down menu.
I also try some other methods but it only work in Firefox, which is not good enough, coz I need to open this from any mobile device.
Pls give me some hints ! Thank you!

Comment: Are you including the jQuery libraries in your page?

Comment: Yes, I included jQuery in my page. And to check the example in the link above, I downloaded all the code and included properly. I would prefer a new method, though.

Comment: Well, you can't do this without using javascript/jQuery. Plain HTML does not support embedding images in a select box.

Comment: Yes, I know, I don't mind using Js, jQuery, css or anything, just to get my purpose! But I mean the example in the link above I already tried and play around and I am looking for different thing. If you can help me to figure out how to make it works, I dont mind trying anything. Simpler for sure is prefered ! :)

Comment: IMO this is better: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: http://bit.ly/14qcnI0

Comment: Yes, I successfully use ddslick, the example at:  https://github.com/devluis/ddslick. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

i have edited ur code plz check

```
    <?php if ($data->URL->Visible) { // URL ?>

            <td<?php echo $data->URL->CellAttributes() ?>>
                <div<?php echo $data->URL->ViewAttributes() ?>><?php echo $data->URL->ListViewValue() ?></div>
                            <select name="webmenu" id="webmenu" >
                                <option value="<?php echo $data->URL->EditValue?>"><?php echo $data->URL->EditValue?></option>
                                <option value="1" data-image="img/tim.png">True</option>
                                <option value="0" data-image="img/do.png">False</option>
                            </select>
            </td>
    <?php } ?>


//plz note this code

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {     
    $("select#webmenu").msDropdown({roundedBorder:false});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't show any image. Only the text is there. I already make sure the all the path for images, etc. is right!